# Insert values from one array to another directly sorted

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

So what I have to do is insert certain values from one array to another one directly sorted without having to sort them later using BubbleSort or QuickSort or any other method. I can't think of a way to do this... I have to insert them from the biggest value to the smallest one. Here's what I have until now:

```
void palindroame (int x[100], int y[100]) {
    int i=0, j, k=0, aux;
    while (x[i]!=0) { 
        k++; i++; 
    }
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<=k-1; i++) y[i]=0;
    for (i=0; i<=k-1; i++) { 
        if (palindrom(x[i])!=0 && palindrom(x[i+1])!=0) 
            if (x[i]<x[i+1]) { 
                aux=x[i+1]; x[i+1]=x[i]; x[i]=aux; 
            } 
    } //wrong
    for (i=0; i<=k-1; i++) { 
        if (palindrom(x[i])) y[i]=x[i]; 
    } //wrong
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are both arrays (you're using arrays and not vectors) sorted to begin with?

Comment: umm, the first array is not sorted (x) and the second one (y) is filled with 0's

Comment: Copying values from an unsorted array so they are in sorted another array **is** sorting. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. It's like saying I want sorted values without doing a sort. You're going to have to do a sort one way or the other.

Comment: I know, I tried explaining the best I could, this is actually an exercise for an exam I'm taking in a few days... what I have to do is take certain values from one array and insert them in another from the biggest to smallest without having to sort them after I inserted, I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain xD

Comment: @IcebirdRo The algorithm you need is selection sort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, you can use this to sort and copy at the same time.

Comment: @john thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed xD add your comment as an answer or something so I can select it and close this question xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - Fastest way to add an item to a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408240/c-fastest-way-to-add-an-item-to-a-sorted-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you need is [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), you can use this to sort and copy at the same time.

Comment: @IcebirdRo Hate to say it but I don't think this answer is correct. You actually want insertion sort, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, I had to sort x though... but it didn't say anywhere that I'm not allowed to sort that, it just said that I'm not allowed to sort y. I'll try with insertion sort too, thanks!

Comment: @IcebirdRo Yes that was the problem I saw. I don't see anyway to use selection sort without sorting the original array. But insertion sort should be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at priority queues:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of a selection sort i have done recently (in which a is a vector)

should give you enough to go on hope it helps, ask questions if u like

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++)
{
    int min = i;

    for(unsigned int j = i +1; j < a.size(); j++)
    {
        // If new minimum is found then stores this as the new minimum
        if(a[j] < a[min])
        {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    // Stores the values in the array in ascending order
    if (min != i)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[min];
        a[min] = temp;
    }
}
// Returns the array in ascending order
return a;
```

Edit: just to clarify this is working on a vector that already has values in it in case that wasnt clear but example with code comments i think is enough to help you IMO