# C++ - Fastest way to add an item to a sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've got a database with approximately 200 000 items, which is sorted by username. Now when I add an item to end of array and call my quick sort function to sort that array it takes almost a second to sort, which is not acceptable. There are definitely quite some optimisations that can be done. For example if I sequentially compare each string from n-1 to 0, and then move items accordingly performance is much greater.

Other idea is that I could perform binary search from 0 to n-1, well not infact search, but something similar to take advantage of my already sorted array. However I've failed to write a proper function that would return an index where my new element should be placed.

```
void quick_sort(int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    if (left >= right) return;
    char  pivotC[128];
    DataEntry *tmp;

    strcpy_a(pivotC, sizeof pivotC, User[(left + right) / 2]->username);

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (StringCompare(User[i]->username, pivotC))
            i++;
        while (StringCompare(pivotC, User[j]->username))
            j--;
        if (i <= j) 
        {
            tmp = User[i];
            User[i] = User[j];
            User[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quick_sort(left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quick_sort(i, right);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: yup , you can use binary searck

Comment: Use STL [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), like  [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). If you can't use them, read about [balanced search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) and use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::sort()`?

Answer (score 9):

the solution is to rewrite your code to use the stl, I don't understand why people write C code in C++.

You need a vector of User

```
std::vector<User> users;
//then you can keep it ordered at each insertion
auto it = upper_bound(users.begin(), users.end(), user_to_insert, 
    [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs ) { /* implementation left to the reader */});
users.insert(it, user_to_insert);
```

You now have the same functionality in a much nicer and clean way

Comment: The predicate needs to take two parameters.

Comment: Also, I believe that you need to use `upper_bound`. `insert` inserts before the iterator, so you need the next element after the theoretical insert location.

Comment: yeah, or reverse the comparison in the lambda, I guess upper_bound is the cleanest however

Comment: @SebastianRedl In a list `{ 1, 4, 5 }` trying to insert `4` (again) using `lower_bound` will lead to `{ 1, (new) 4, 4, 5 }`; if we'd used `uppoer_bound` we'd have `{ 1, 4, (new) 4, 5 }`. How does it make a difference? In fact using `lower_bound` on may skip insertion knowing the element already exists. Using `upper_bound` we'd've to make a `--` on the iterator to verify if the element already exists.

Comment: @legends2k You are right, I somehow thought that `lower_bound({ 1, 3, 4 }, 2)` would return the iterator pointing to `1`. That's of course wrong, so `lower_bound` works, and as you pointed out, is better if you want to eliminate duplicates. (If, on the other hand, you have lots and lots of duplicates, `upper_bound` is a tiny bit faster since it has to move fewer elements.)

Comment: _`upper_bound` [...] has to move fewer elements_ How? Both would look for x, then `upper_bound` would've to move across all the dupes of `x` to point to `x + 1` (i.e. element greater than `x`) so still `lower_bound` is better, no? Or perhaps equal since `lower_bound` has to work too to get to the beginning of `x`s.

Comment: "I don't understand why people write C code in C++" - C is a lot easier and no magic, c++ loads of magic. raw pointers vs smart pointers, easiest decision of my life, raw - thug life.

Answer (score 3):

Reinventing the wheel is fine if you want to learn how to code binary search, otherwise reusing is better.

[`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) performs a binary search on a sorted range `[first, last)`, returning an iterator to the searched element `x` if already present; otherwise the iterator would be pointing to the first element greater than `x`. Since standard containers' exposing an `insert` would insert before the iterator, this iterator can be used as-is. Here's a simple example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> data = { 1, 5, 7, 8, 12, 34, 52 };

    auto loc = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 10);
    // you may insert 10 here using loc
    std::cout << *loc << '\n';

    loc = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 12);
    // you may skip inserting 12 since it is in the list (OR)
    // insert it if you need to; it'd go before the current 12
    std::cout << *loc << '\n';
}
```

> 12
>
> 12

Answer (score 1):

Easy , direct method cause binary searching is too mainstream. Just need a few lines:

```
int where_to_add(int array[], int element)
{
    int i;
    for (i = length; i >= 0 && array[i-1] > element; i--);
    return i;
}
```

*Let me know if this is the answer you were looking for*

Answer (score 1):

Binary search will be of limited interest, as you will need to insert anyway and this will remain a time consuming operation (O(N)). So your first idea of a linear search followed by insertion is good enough; you can combine in a single backward loop. (This is a step of StraightInsertionSort.)

The truly efficient ways to handle dynamic sorted lists are by maintaining a balanced tree or using a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sorting a sorted list with only a few new out of place trailing items then you should take advantage of the rare case in which insertion sort actually works efficiently. Implementing insertion sort on a sorted list with only a few trailing out of place values can sort in O(n) time. You're just inserting your few out of place values into place, while quick sort is picking a pivot and going through the entire quick sort process. Also, if you're not incorporating some type of efficient pivot selection process into your quick sort, and going with some "average of first 3 items" approach on an already sorted list you're going to be sorting in O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do binary search like this way.. Here You can assume that if val is string type then compare using string comparison function and int AR[] is set of string or You can map them to integer. As the array is sorted , I think binary search will give you the best performance.

```
int bsearch(int AR[], int N, int VAL)
{
    int Mid,Lbound=0,Ubound=N-1;

    while(Lbound<=Ubound)
    {
        Mid=(Lbound+Ubound)/2;
        if(VAL>AR[Mid])
            Lbound=Mid+1;
        else if(VAL<AR[Mid])
            Ubound=Mid-1;
        else
            return Mid;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're using a C array to store your entries, which means a big penalty in performance with huge number of entries whenever you try to insert an new entry because you may need to move a lot of entries in the array.

If you plan to keep a C array and not using some stl ordered containers (mostly thinking about std::map though), you may try to split your C array into two arrays. One will be a first array containing your key and an index to an element of the second array. You still need to sort the first array but its element is only two words (one for key, one for index) instead of a big block including key and some values) and should be faster. When inserting an item, you allocate at the end of the second array and take the index to insert it as a pair with key inside the first array. If you plan to remove an element dynamically, you can be a little smarter but your question appears not to cover it.

But even so, it might be still too slow, so you should indeed consider std::map or some algorithms like binary tree using AVL, Red Black tree, Splay tree, etc. where you do not need to move element physically.

Answer (score -1):

```
int add(Container c, int r, int l, Unit t)
{
    if(c[r]>t)
        return r;
    if(c[l]<t)
        return l+1;
    if(c[r]==c[l])
    {
         if(c[r]==t)
            return -1;
         return -1;
    }
    int m=(r+l)/2;
    if(c[m]==t)
          return -1;
    if(c[m]>t)
          return add(c,m,l,t);
    if(c[m]<t)
          return add(c,r,m,t);
}
```

It will probably give you the index you need to add...I hope it can help.It assumes you do not need to add when its already in.

Comment: right(r) left(l) middle(m) container(c) t(the object ve find its place) And it returns the position of correct place u push that object